# Double click on text causes illogical selection

Tags: javascript, html

Double clicking on reference causes strange selection as shown in image below. This is happening in chrome, not in firefox.

Appreciate any advice or fix.

[image]

Comment: you can't fix it. It's the compilation of bootstrap by chrome. 
each style are compiled differently by each browser